# SVG Animation rotate in steps

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I currently have a CSS animation to rotate a spinner **in 12 steps** (see snippet).

Instead of this I want to apply the animation inside the SVG code itself (so that the spinner rotates when loaded as a CSS background-image).

I have added the following inside the `<svg>`:

```
<animateTransform
  attributeType="xml"
  attributeName="transform"
  type="rotate"
  from="0 12 12"
  to="360 12 12"
  dur="2s"
  repeatCount="indefinite"
  />
```

This rotates the spinner - but not in steps. What do I have to add?

Thanks! :)

```css
svg {
    height: 24px;
    fill: black;
    animation: spinner 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
  }
  
@keyframes spinner {
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.918" transform="rotate(330,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.836" transform="rotate(300,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.755" transform="rotate(270,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.673" transform="rotate(240,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.591" transform="rotate(210,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.509" transform="rotate(180,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.427" transform="rotate(150,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.345" transform="rotate(120,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.264" transform="rotate(90,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.182" transform="rotate(60,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
 <path style="opacity:.1" transform="rotate(30,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I test you code for several times, `steps` work well, just change `12` to `2` or `3` and see the proof. But for your case that say you wanna have it inside `SVG` I undoubtedly suggest do not do that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `calcMode="discrete"` and provide a `tableValues` attribute listing all the steps values.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <g>
    <path d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.918" transform="rotate(330,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.836" transform="rotate(300,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.755" transform="rotate(270,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.673" transform="rotate(240,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.591" transform="rotate(210,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.509" transform="rotate(180,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.427" transform="rotate(150,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.345" transform="rotate(120,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.264" transform="rotate(90,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.182" transform="rotate(60,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <path style="opacity:.1" transform="rotate(30,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                      attributeName="transform"
                      type="rotate"
                      dur="1s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"
                      calcMode="discrete"
                      values="0 12 12; 30 12 12; 60 12 12; 90 12 12; 120 12 12; 150 12 12; 180 12 12; 210 12 12; 240 12 12; 270 12 12; 300 12 12; 330 12 12"
  </g>
</svg>
```

But you could have also just included the CSS in the SVG.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <style>
    svg {
      height: 24px;
      fill: black;
      animation: spinner 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
    }

    @keyframes spinner {
      to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
  </style>
  <path d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.918" transform="rotate(330,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.836" transform="rotate(300,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.755" transform="rotate(270,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.673" transform="rotate(240,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.591" transform="rotate(210,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.509" transform="rotate(180,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.427" transform="rotate(150,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.345" transform="rotate(120,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.264" transform="rotate(90,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.182" transform="rotate(60,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
  <path style="opacity:.1" transform="rotate(30,12,12)" d="M12,2 a1,1 0 0 1 1,1 v3 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,1 a1,1 0 0 1 -1,-1 v-3 a1,1 0 0 1 1,-1 z"/>
</svg>
```